# Reading a random line from a txt file, then trim it in QT SDK

Tags: c++, qt

I'd like to ask your help with my little school project.
The task is to determine a person's gender (using 2 radio buttons) and then pick a random Japanese family name and male/female middlename. And there's the rest of the task, but it's nothing compared to this part :( 
Thing is, i have managed to make the 3 .txt files (familynames.txt, malemiddlenames.txt and femalemiddlenames.txt) look like the following: 
1,Akiro
2,Sakura
3,etc...

What i'd like to do is create a random number, and read the lines until it arrives to the line with the same number as my random number, then cut the number and the comma off, and display the name on the corresponding label. So far this is what i've got:

```
void MainWindow::famname()
{
    QString familyname;
    int famrand =qrand() % 76;
    ui->label_2->setText(QString::number(famrand));
    int i = 1;

    QFile famfile("C:\Users\Ryseth\gyakorlas\_familynames.txt");
    QTextStream in(&famfile);
    if(famfile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)){

        while (!in.atEnd()) {
             QString line = in.readLine();
             i++;
             if(i==famrand){
                 QStringList line2 =line.split(',');
                 familyname = line2.at(0);
                 ui->label_2->setText(QString::number(famrand)+" "+QString::number(i));
                 ui->FamilyLabel->setText(familyname);
             }//IF
         }//WHILE
    }//IF
         famfile.close();
}//NGEN
```

If any of you could think of some sort of solution or if you have ANY suggestions, please don't hasitate to share it with me :D

Thank you, and have a nice day/night : Ruben

Comment: How about "read lines into an array", and pick an element at random from the array. Reading a "random" line in a file still involves scanning through the file for newlines until you are at the line you want.

Comment: It crossed my mind as well, but then i took the harder way :D

Comment: Are you going to generate more than one name during the application lifetime? If yes, then reading all lines to array (only once) would be much better approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think with Boost::Spirit::Qi you could parse your file into a `std::vector< std::string >` and do your operation with simple c++ methods.

But to help you with your Qt-Solution:

You never check if `int famrand =qrand() % 76;` produces a legal number, are there enough entries in your text file ...

`int i = 1;` This integer is unnecessary, the number is within the text file ...

My solution (untested):

```
while (!in.atEnd()) {
  QString line = in.readLine();
  QStringList list = line.split(",", QString::SkipEmptyParts);
  bool ok;
  int idx = list.at(0).toInt(&ok);
  if (ok && idx == famrand) {
    familyname = list.at(1).trimmed();
    // ... do with your ui whatever you want
  }//IF
}//WHILE
```

Keep in mind you have to do error handling if the conversion of string to int fails and/or the accessors of list throw (`list.at(xx)`)

**The positive thing is, you dont need an ordered text file!**

Comment: Hi, and thank you for your response. Theoritically it should work ( at least i don't get any error msg.-es when i debug it. howerver it doesn't recognise the text file =( Doesn't matter if i copy it to the project's location(and simply call it with "QFile famfile(_familynames.txt)") or use the path of the destination folder (C:\Users\Ryseth\gyakorlas\_familynames.txt). Apart from this it seems to work great.

Comment: a made a project and it works fine ...
are you sure that your famrand is valid (e.g. there is an corresponding value within the textfile?)
furthermore, there was a mistake (familyname = list.at(1).trimmed();)

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you are managing to do but at this line I guess you are getting the number, not the familyname.

```
familyname = line2.at(0); // number
familyname = line2.at(1); // family name
```

Comment: well umm, i wish to return the family name of a random line in the txt file and display it in a Label.i guess that's why i need the  'familyname = line2.at(1);' part